# In which extensions of type $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is the number 3 reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $O$ be the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is a square free negative number.
Assume that the number 3 is reducible in $O$. Prove that $d = -2,-3,$ or $-11$.

Thank you for the help.

---

First there is problem to talk about norm where $d \lt -11$.
There is a theorem that says when $d \lt -11$ the ring $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ isn't Euclidean.
What can I do when $d \lt -11$ ?

Comment: What do you mean reducible? Where the ideal $3$ splits?

Comment: @AlexYoucis reducible = not irreducible, I'd think. So there are (algebraic) integers $a,b$, neither a unit, with $a\cdot b = 3$. (Yes, of course that means the ideal splits, but the more elementary viewpoint of considering elements is probably more appropriate here.)

Comment: Are you aware of the norm on $O$?